# What's the $R^2$ between X and Y if change in X and the change in Y are correlated?

Tags: correlation, econometrics

Suppose $\Delta Y_t$ = $\beta_0 + \beta_1 \Delta X_t + u_t$ has an $R^2$ of 0.9. Is it possible to calculate the $R^2$ between $X$ and $Y$?

Answer (score 1):

If $X_t$ is a random process, e.g. ARIMA(p, 1, q), then you cannot know the $R^2$.  The important thing to realize here is that the influence of innovations from $X_t$, an integrated time series, on its future observations do not decay over time, but their effect on $y_t$ does.

The $R^2$ statistic you get will essentially be nonsense, and should be taken with a grain of salt.  Granger and Newbold pointed this out in their paper Spurious Regressions in Economics (http://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/zal/STAT758/Granger_Newbold_1974.pdf).  They note the following three things about regressing integrated time series on each other without first differencing:

(i) Estimates of the regression coefficients are inefficient.

(ii) Forecasts based on the regression equations are sub-optimal.

(iii) The usual significance tests on the coefficients are invalid.